When calling docusign at document, always getting AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN error message
Here account details:
$integrationKey = '9eaed807-bd9f-4d38-b858-37f6eccc6b73'; // Your Integration Key
$userId = 'd4300ed6-aa42-47cd-b687-01c825726abd'; // Your User ID (GUID)
$accountId = '8c637b59-afa2-4821-8c5d-981bacf4ddde'; // Your Account ID

When trying to sign with PHP, always getting this error:
Error sending envelope:

Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code
[401] with response Body:
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:27:"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN";s:7:"message";s:59:"The
access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed.";}

Please check and suggest solutions.
Want to get success response.

You didn't provide the actual code, but here is PHP code that works for what you need to do:
(the code is at https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/JWTService.php)
 self::$apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['authorization_server']);
        $privateKey = file_get_contents(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['private_key_file'],
            true
        );

        $scope = (new DocuSign())->getDefaultScopes()[0];
        $jwt_scope = $scope;

        try {
            $response = self::$apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'],
                $aud = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
                $aud = $privateKey,
                $aud = $jwt_scope
            );

            return $response[0]; 

$envelope_definition = EmbeddedSigningService::makeEnvelope($args["envelope_args"], $demoPath, $pdfFile);
        $envelope_api = $clientService->getEnvelopeApi();

        # Call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        try {
            $envelopeSummary = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($args['account_id'], $envelope_definition);
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            $clientService->showErrorTemplate($e);
            exit;
        }
        $envelope_id = $envelopeSummary->getEnvelopeId();

